# Hashmap as Property Value in Janusgraph

Tags: json, gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

I use a janusgraph docker container. I connect with it via tinkerpop remote connection in my Java application.

I want to set a hashmap as property value on a specific node. That should be possible because Janusgraph has a native attribute serializer for HashMaps. (see: https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/master/janusgraph-core/src/main/java/org/janusgraph/graphdb/database/serialize/StandardSerializer.java)

But:

```
HashMap<Object,Object> myMap = new HashMap();
myMap.put("aKey","aValue");
g.V(someId).property("propKey",myMap).iterate();
```

result in gremlin converting my HashMap into a LinkedHashMap what results in following message:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Datatype is not supported by
> database since no serializer has been registered: class
> java.util.LinkedHashMap

I already tried to add the property by adding a ByteCode step:

`traversal.asAdmin().getBytecode().addStep(GraphTraversal.Symbols.property,myMap)`

and using json:

```
Bindings bindings = Bindings.instance();
g.V(someId).property("propKey",objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myMap)).iterate();
//for some reason this results in an IndexOutOfBound Exception on janusgraph site
```

And I also added the property with datatype=java.util.HashMap to the schema but nothing worked.
Some suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

From a quick look in the TinkerPop code, the conversion to LinkedHashMap seems to occur for the kryo serializer (https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/gremlin-go/v3.6.4/gremlin-core/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/io/gryo/UtilSerializers.java)
Does the issue also occur when using the `conf/remote-graph-binary.yaml` configuration file for the gremlin-client?